# AWS Amplify Cloning repository error: “Basic Auth is not supported for SSR apps.”

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, build-error, aws-amplify, cicd

I have an app in AWS Amplify. I have restricted access control in the app settings with credentials. When I turn off the restrictions to publicly viewable but when i turn on the restricted again, the build fails in AWS amplify?
I can't understand. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Redeploy the version of  Amplify App you can find this option inside you amplify app settings.